# Kendo grid changes name of column after grouping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using MVC wrappers to create kendo grids and everytime i want to group a row the Title of the column gets ignored. It doesnt matter if the title is set in the grid .Title("") or in the viewmodel [Display(Name="")]. The result is the same. Any opinions on this?

I have added an example how it looks like when i group a column http://prntscr.com/3nm8rk

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
              .Name("GridEkstenzija" + guid)
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<img style='   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'" + "width='24' height='24' src='" + Url.Action("UcitajSlikuEkstenzije") + '/' + "#:data.IdEkstenzija#' />").Title(EkstenzijeDatotekaLanguage.Icon);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Ekstenzija);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Opis);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.MimeType);
                  columns.ForeignKey(f => f.StatusId, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.StatusEkstenzija, "IdStatus", "Naziv").Title("Status");
              })

                              .Selectable(sel => sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                                      .Sortable().Pageable(pg =>
                  {
                      pg.PageSizes(new[] { 20, 50, 100, 300 });
                      pg.Refresh(true).Numeric(true
                          ).Messages(ms => ms.First(Resources.KendoPageableFirst).Last(Resources.KendoPageableLast).Next(Resources.KendoPageableNext).Previous(Resources.KendoPageablePrevious).Empty(Resources.KendoPageableEmpty)
                              .ItemsPerPage(Resources.KendoItemsPerPage).Display(Resources.KendoPageableDisplay));
                  })
                              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().PageSize(10)
                                  .ServerOperation(false).Model(model => model.Id(p => p.IdEkstenzija))
                                  .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "EkstenzijaDatoteke").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))))
```

Comment: no ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Easy solution could be not to use the *ForeignKey* functionality, but just return all the data you need

Comment: @Goran303 did you ever find a solution for this? My Kendo Grid is suddenly ignoring my Display attribute resulting in my column headers getting the wrong names. I've removed grouping and just about everything else, but it does have any effect.